# Limit of two variable

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Suppose that I have equation:

$$\tan(a) = \dfrac{b-c}{bc + 1},\;\text{ where }\,a, b, c\, \text{ are variables.}$$

How can I show that, as $a \to \pi/2, \; bc+1\to 0\;$ mathematically, not intuitively.

I know how to calculate limit, as variable $(X,Y)$ approaches to $(X_0,Y_0)$, but not the other way.

How can I find point where $(X,Y)$ approaches, when the limit is given, mathematically rather than intuitively?

Comment: To format write pi with a backlash: $\backslash  pi$ and put it between dollar signs.

Comment: Isn't it true in general that if $a_n/b_n\rightarrow\infty$ and $a_n$ does not go to infinity, that $b_n$ must go to zero?

Comment: You cannot show this, because it's wrong. You could have $c={1\over b}$ and $b\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving for $c$, we have
$$ c = \frac{ b - \tan a }{ b \tan a + 1 } = \frac{b \cos a- \sin a}{b \sin a + \cos a}$$

Then, writing $b^\star$ and $c^\star$ for $\lim b$ and $\lim c$ as $a\to\pi/2$ (*assuming* both limits exist), 
$$c^\star = \frac{b^\star \cos\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin\frac{\pi}{2}}{b^\star \sin\frac{\pi}{2}+\cos\frac{\pi}{2}} = \frac{-1}{b^\star}$$
so that $b^\star c^\star + 1 = 0$. That is, $bc+1\to 0$, as claimed. $\square$

Comment: If you assume from the start that $b$ and $c$ have finite limits the claim is obvious, and you don't have to go through these complications.

Answer (score 0):

If $A \to \pi/2$ then $\tan(A)\to +\infty$ supposed the value of $A$ is ever less than $\pi/2$, because $\tan$ is continuous on the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Since our equality holds, $bc+1=\frac{c^2+1}{1-c\tan a}$, so there are $b$ and $c$ for every $a$ that $bc+1=1$, which shows we need another assumptions too to show $bc+1\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that as $a$ goes to $\pi/2$, $\tan(a)$ goes to infinity.  So in the right hand side of your expression either the numerator goes to infinity or the denominator goes to zero.  If the numerator goes to infinity, either $b$ goes to infinity or $c$ goes to -infinity (or both).  But you can see if b or c have this behavior, the fraction does not go to infinity.  Therefore, the only alternative is that $bc+1$ goes to zero.

Comment: For this question answer provided by blue is enough. But in general, i think we need to check all critical conditions, As you did here... Your approach is Similar to in my mind. I wish i can vote up but not enough reputation.